# Where can I find the .desktop files for the "Copy To" and "Move To" service menus for Dolphin file browser

Tags: kde, file-copy, move, servicemenu

I am using KDE Neon. I want to create modified versions of the "Move To" and "Copy To" services in the Dolphin file browser.
I want to find the built-in services, copy their .desktop files, and edit the copies, making a new pair of services with the new option. 
I ran `kf5-config --path services` and got /home/myusername/.local/share/kservices5/:/usr/share/kservices5/ I checked in both of these locations and could not find .desktop files which appeared to be related to Copy To or Move to.

Do Copy To and Move To even have .desktop files associated with them? If so, where would I find them.

Comment: I asked here: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/dmg3my/where_are_the_desktop_files_for_all_the_services/. Let's hope someone answers.

Comment: Well, Zren, a Plasma developer, [has explained](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/dmg3my/where_are_the_desktop_files_for_all_the_services/f50jcfu?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) that these are *dynamically* generated. All the same, why can't you just make your own from scratch? I looked at examples from the [KDE Store](https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/102/) to make the .desktop files for the service menus I wanted.

Comment: @DKBose Thank you very much.

Comment: If you expand a bit more on what you want to do, perhaps it would be relatively simple to come up with what you want. Please see https://askubuntu.com/q/1179100/248158. I'm sure it's not the best way to do things but it works for the specific question asked there. Maybe you don't need to move stuff to root-owned folders in which case the code would be simpler.